# SCRIPT1014: Invalid Character in IE11

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer

I have created a new vue 3 project using Vue CLI and keep getting this error from IE11. The error is coming from Vue.js module.

Does anyone have solution for this error?

Comment: You know Vue 3 is still in beta, right? See https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/issues/183

Answer (score 1):

for Vue 3.0: found the following info -

Migration and IE11 Support

We have pushed back the migration build (v3 build with v2 compatible behavior + migration warnings) and the IE11 build due to time constraints, and are aiming to focus on them in Q4 2020. Therefore, users planning to migrate an existing v2 app or require IE11 support should be aware of these limitations at this time.

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/releases/tag/v3.0.0